# If I use "Rigify addon" , should I roll the bones axes ? even directions of them?

Tags: rigify

I would like to know if whenever I use an addon modifier called "rigify" should I always check the roll bones (rolls of the bones)? specially in the finger??

I know how to rig basics but manually, I have seen some tutorials of that addon, but people never touched the rolls bones or even some adjustment in the constraint, angles, rotation in chains... however I think the addon is powerful, but it is automatic...

I would like to know if some advanced 3d artist prefer the old method, or this ? even "mocap" is the best way, but I am able to use just the addon rigify and metarig.

What are your opinions guys, should I use the rigify addon ? and make sure to check in bones properties the rolling bones, the axes direction.  My question sounds more than an advice than a question, but consider it.

Comment: You should perhaps try to ask about issues or doubts you find with the rigify addon... when there are different methods, everyone will prefer one or the other... in the end only you can decide what fits best...

Comment: The finger part is really a duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42545/rigify-finger-controls-rotation-not-moving-correctly which I just answered, but since the answer is not upvoted I can't mark as dupe. The other aspects of this question are primarily opinion based.

Comment: Ok I ve read the thread you ve written in the past. Well I suppose I must roll for fingers too...not way to get the best even if it is automatic.