# i am stuck on how to weight paint my human character using the rigify add-on

Tags: armature, weight-painting, rigify

i am trying to weightpaint my character. I have used the riify add-on to rig it. I do not know what the relationship between the rigify rig and weight painting is. Do i paint on the human meta rig? I am trying to make it so that i can control my character using the rigify rig. I know how to weightpaint the human meta rig but i am unsure how to approach it with rigify. Help would be really appreciated as i am desperate to get animating after making this character for so long! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The *metarig* is only used to lay out the bones on the mesh. I recommend a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/gqvH0Qj-aus) if you're not familiar with Rigify.

Place the character model so that it stands on the "ground" (soles of the feet at z=0). Make sure you have applied *All Transformations* (scale, location, rotation) to the mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (in *Object* mode) before you start. The bones of the elbows and knees should be bent slightly.

When you're happy with the layout, apply *All Transformations* to the *metarig*, then press the <kbd>Generate Rig</kbd> button. You can use this button more than once. Rigify can override the generated rig. See section button *Advanced Options*.

The *Generate Rig* button creates the actual rig. It's just named "*rig*" and has all the control bones and deform bones (layer 30) on different layers.

After you have created the generated rig you can parent it to the mesh with *Automatic Weights* and test it in *Pose* mode.

There might be some issues that need to be fixed.

- The fingers might need some corrections. To make the fingers "grab" you need to scale the red handle. If it doesn't work proper have a look here: [Rigify finger controls rotation not moving correctly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42545/rigify-finger-controls-rotation-not-moving-correctly)
- The eye lids you might have to weight paint manually. And you need to parent the eyeballs to a bone of the rig to make them follow the control. [Video: Fixing the Metarig - The SECRETS of RIGIFY: Part 3](https://youtu.be/UpAxY519IJU) and [Weight Painting - The SECRETS of RIGIFY: Part 4! - [Blender 2.8]](https://youtu.be/3GZE5bjZXbA)
- The teeth and tongue might need some weight painting

Comment: Thanks! I am really grateful for your advice and it has helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The main things you should understand are:

1. The meta rig is just a way to build the Generated rig. You always parent and weight paint with the Generated rig.
2. The Deformation bones of the Generated rig are on layer 29 which is hidden by default. So you weight paint Rigify like any other rig but you have to unhide layer 29 first.