# Scaling not coming properly on rig

Tags: rigging

[image: screenshot of rigged left hand]

Hope all are well. I tried human meta rig. After successfully placed bones I clicked generate rig button. Rig also comes perfectly. But while I check the finger bones all are good except pinky bones. While I tried to scale the fk tweaks are moving reverse. Any one could you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: It looks as if the bone roll direction is completely wrong on the lower bone of that finger. The Z axes of all the bones except that one are pointing down towards the palm, but that one is pointing towards the wrist. Difficult to tell without seeing the blend file though.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42545/rigify-finger-controls-rotation-not-moving-correctly?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, where often Rigify isn't able to find the correct bending direction of fingers.

To solve select your MetaRig, in edit mode set the bone roll of all fingers bones so that the main rotation will happen on positive values of X axis.

Then switch to pose mode, select the first bone of every finger and switch its bend rotation preference from "Automatic" to "X axis".

Then generate the Rig.

[image]