# Rigify: Arm not Rotating Correctly

Tags: rigging, rigify

I set up the rigify human meta-rig, paying attention to bone rolls as described [here.](https://wiki.blender.jp/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:Addon_Rigify_0.5_arm_bones_positions.png) I calculated roll with shift-N then rotated to the roll with control-R accordingly. I calculated to +Z Global because this had all of the bone rolls consistent. Here you can see my rig with the axises. It appears to follow the rigify documentation. My bone rolls: [image: My bone rolls.]
When I generate my rigify rig the arm axis rotations aren't aligned. See what I mean here: [image: here]
In local space, with rotation point set to individual origins, when I rotate up on z I move backwards slightly. This would make for messy graph editing while animating.
Does anybody know what is causing this? I thought I got the bone rolls correct. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also think that the default rot of Rigify rigs isn't well suited for graph editor editing.

You can change this behaviour selecting the Metarig, then go to pose mode, select the first bone of the arm bones chain and change its rotation axis from "Automatic" to "X manual" in its Rigify Type preferences.

In a similar way you can correct bad axis rot in fingers (a very common problem), knowing that scaling the main control will force bones to rotate on X positive axis.

Then generate the rig.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. You can see me previously working through the fingers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42545/rigify-finger-controls-rotation-not-moving-correctly